# iOS TableViewController push segue to another TableViewController causes strange graphical glitch

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, storyboard

With Swift, I'm trying to push segue from one TableViewController to another when I'm selecting a table view cell from the first, however. This occurs.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wiauv.jpg

Is there any reason for it? Storyboard in the album too

Comment: Are they both `UITableViewControllers` or is either one of them a `UIViewController` with a `UITableView`?

Comment: They are both `UITableViewControllers`